# Email NSMutableString in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, mailto, nsmutablestring

I am sending a NSMutableString through the body of an email.
It will not work because it says senderString cannot by statically located. Help?

```
NSMutableString *senderString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

NSURL *mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"mailto:email@address.com?cc=another@email.com&subject=My%20Subject%20Line&body=%@"], senderString;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: mailURL];
```

Comment: So you've got a compiler error?

Comment: yes, the error is when I use senderString in the same line as all the email info

Comment: Why not use `MFMailComposeViewController` to allow the user to send the email from your app?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your inclusion of `senderString` on the end of the line declaring the `mailURL`. I'm assuming you're trying to set the `senderString` as the body of the email.

If that is the case, you'll need to do something like this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
  @"mailto:email@address.com?cc=another@email.com&subject=My%%20Subject%%20Line&body=%@",
 senderString];
```

And it's worth mentioning that if the `senderString` isn't already percent escaped as required for use in a url, you'll need to do something like this first (i.e. before the `stringWithFormat` call):

```
senderString = [senderString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then you can just construct the `mailURL` like this:

```
NSURL *mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

**Update:** I've added escaping for the percent in `%20` and added a recommendation to escape the `senderString` parameter, as suggested by rmaddy.

Comment: You need to replace the `%20` with `%%20` since this string is now a format string. To put a `%` character in the string you need to escape it so it is `%%`.

Comment: And you need to call `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` on `senderString`.

Comment: @rmaddy Excellent point about the % escaping. I've updated the answer. As for the senderString escaping, I got the impression from one of his comments that that was already escaped, or at least didn't need escaping. Although, thinking about it now, I should probably at least mention that in the answer. Thanks.